# SQL Server: (implicit?) date conversion failure from text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the something akin to the following code:

```
DECLARE @EvalDate VARCHAR(254)
SET @Evaldate = '''4/30/2017'',''12/31/2016'',''12/31/2015'',''12/31/2014'',''12/31/2013'''

SELECT field1, field2, YEAR(datefield1) AS YR, datefield2
FROM table 
WHERE datefield2 IN (@EvalDate)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm pretty sure that the error comes from my `SET @Evaldate` statement since this used to run when I just entered the dates directly into the WHERE/IN clause. How can I correct this?

I am using SQL Server 2008 btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error isn't from your `SET` command, it's from your `WHERE` statement.  It's trying to convert the literal value `'4/30/2017','12/31/2016','12/31/2015','12/31/2014','12/31/2013'` into a date, and obviously failing.

You can't use a variable to insert multiple values into an `IN` like that.  What this is doing is attempting to convert the entire string into a single date, and failing.

This should give you the results you want using a `TABLE` variable and doing a  `JOIN` to it:

```
Declare @Dates Table
(
    EvalDate Date
)

Insert  @Dates (EvalDate)
Values  ('2017-04-30'),
        ('2016-12-31'),
        ('2015-12-31'),
        ('2014-12-31'),
        ('2013-12-31');

SELECT  field1, field2, YEAR(datefield1) AS YR, datefield2
FROM    table   T
Join    @Dates  D   On  D.EvalDate = T.DateField2
```

Additionally, you should always use the ISO standard date format (`yyyy-MM-dd`).

Comment: My preferred date format is "MMM dd yyyy", i.e. "Jun 7, 2017". Barring language considerations, it's really hard to get confused with this.